Back-swipe on chromebook needed twice in html-based Android app
I made an android app based on a very simple html. It's a single page ajax based site.  Here's the html page served on github pages:
https://vicmortelmans.github.io/alledaags-geloven-cocoon/
Navigation: you click an item, some html is fetched from a server and is displayed and in JavaScript the history is updated: window.history.pushState({}, window.document.title, '');.
When going back in the browser, the JavaScript is triggered by the popstate event to redraw the start screen:
            $(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
              [modifying page body...]
              return false;
            });

This html is packaged as an android app (using appilix.com): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.gelovenleren.alledaags
The behaviour of the back button/swipe is OK on any platform that I tested, EXCEPT on my chromebook in tablet mode. When I swipe from the left edge to go back, I have to do it twice. On the first swipe, the shelf pops up (why?) and on the second swipe the app is actually going back to the start page. Note that when the Chromebook is flipped in laptop mode, using the keyboard back button works fine!
I don't see this problem on any other android app on my Chromebook, so I suspect it's something to do with my app, but I can't imagine what might be going on!
